# Having issues with constraints not looking like I expect them to Xcode Storyboard mode

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I'm trying to have my switch hug the right side of the view like it does in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape mode it pretty much ignores my constraint.

The constraints seem to work fine outside of the scrollview.

Any tips or suggestions on how to overcome this? Pictures included to show what I mean

[image: Here we have a constraint from the switch to the trailing space to the container]

[image: Here in landscape, the constraint is totally ignored]

Comment: What constraints did you set exactly?

Comment: Well the switch has constraints leading to trailing set to equal @ constant 20. Verticle space constraint is set to equal 15. Then finally a Center Y alignment Constraint between the Label and the Switch. For some reason, the leading to trailing constraint set at 20 is being ignored and I don't understand why. Probably something to do with it being inside a scroll view?

Comment: Are you seeing any constraint exceptions logged in the console?

Comment: I don't see any constraint exceptions

Comment: Leading to trailing of what? Are you talking about the label or the superview? The switch should have a constraint between it and the right side of the superview if you want it to stay on the right side. There should be no horizontal constraint between the label and the switch.

Comment: Again, theres no horizontal constraint, there is a Center Y alignment constraint. Leading to trailing of the scrollview.

Comment: Give the scroll view a background color so you can see what its size is in landscape. It could be that the scroll view has the same width in landscape as it has in portrait, which would put your switch right where you see it.